# Binary Indexed Tree implementation with test cases

Tags: java

This is a an implementation of Binary Indexed Tree. This passes all the test cases listed below and works as intended. I'm using Java 11.

*What I need reviewed:*

- Can this be simplified with any new feature in Java versions 8-11?
- Any other improvements?

---

> **Binary Indexed Tree**
>
> A Fenwick tree or binary indexed tree is a data structure that can
>   efficiently update elements and calculate prefix sums in a table of
>   numbers. Both operations are \$O(log(n))\$
>
> [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree)

**BinaryIndexedTree.java**

```
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * BinaryIndexedTree allows faster ranges sums of O(log(n))
 * However increasing a single index with delta is also O(log(n))
 * Note: This doesn't check for overflow
 *
 * @author Bhathiya
 */
public class BinaryIndexedTree {
    private final long[] internalData;
    private final int size;

    /**
     * Construct from given array
     *
     * @param originalArray original array to process
     */
    public BinaryIndexedTree(long[] originalArray) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(originalArray);
        this.size = originalArray.length;
        internalData = new long[size + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            increase(i, originalArray[i]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Construct an empty BinaryIndexedTree
     *
     * @param size element count
     */
    public BinaryIndexedTree(int size) {
        if (size < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Size cannot be less than zero");
        this.size = size;
        internalData = new long[size + 1];
    }


    /**
     * Increase given index with value delta
     * similar to array[index] += delta
     *
     * @param index index in array
     * @param delta value to add to specific index
     */
    public void increase(int index, long delta) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= size) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
        index += 1;
        while (index <= this.size) {
            internalData[index] += delta;
            // WHY:
            // Faster way to get the last set bit of index using 2's complement
            //  then we add it to index to find all cells that needs to be incremented
            index += index & (-index);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Calculate sum of values in array[0] ... array[index] (inclusive)
     *
     * @param index index in array
     * @return sum
     */
    public long sumUpTo(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= size) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
        int sum = 0;
        index += 1;
        while (index > 0) {
            sum += internalData[index];
            // WHY:
            // Faster way to get the last set bit of index using 2's complement
            //  then we subtract it from index to find all cells that contains values that
            //  we need to add to `sum` variable so we can find sumUpTo given original index
            index -= index & (-index);
        }
        return sum;
    }

    /**
     * Calculate sum of array[fromIndex] .. array[toIndex]
     *
     * @param fromIndex range from index in array
     * @param toIndex   range to index in array
     * @return sum of elements in specified index range
     */
    public long rangeSum(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        if (fromIndex == 0) {
            return sumUpTo(toIndex);
        }
        return sumUpTo(toIndex) - sumUpTo(fromIndex - 1);
    }

    /**
     * @return size of BinaryIndexedTree
     */
    public int size() {
        return this.size;
    }
}
```

**BinaryIndexedTreeTest.java**

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class BinaryIndexedTreeTest {
    @Test
    public void testIncrease() {
        long[] original = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        BinaryIndexedTree binaryIndexedTree = new BinaryIndexedTree(original);
        binaryIndexedTree.increase(0, 5);
        // now first element should be 6, therefore sum of element 0 .. 0 is 6.
        Assert.assertEquals(binaryIndexedTree.sumUpTo(0), 6);
        // sum of elements at indexes  0 .. 1 is 8
        Assert.assertEquals(binaryIndexedTree.sumUpTo(1), 8);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIncreaseSingleElement() {
        long[] original = {1};
        BinaryIndexedTree binaryIndexedTree = new BinaryIndexedTree(original);
        binaryIndexedTree.increase(0, 5);
        // now first element should be 6, therefore sum of element 0 .. 0 is 6.
        Assert.assertEquals(binaryIndexedTree.sumUpTo(0), 6);
    }

    @Test(expectedExceptions = IndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
    public void testEmptyArraySum() {
        long[] original = {};
        BinaryIndexedTree binaryIndexedTree = new BinaryIndexedTree(original);
        Assert.assertEquals(binaryIndexedTree.sumUpTo(0), 0);
    }

    @Test(expectedExceptions = IndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
    public void testEmptyArraySumWithSizeConstructor() {
        BinaryIndexedTree binaryIndexedTree = new BinaryIndexedTree(0);
        Assert.assertEquals(binaryIndexedTree.sumUpTo(0), 0);
    }

    @Test(expectedExceptions = IndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
    public void testEmptyArrayIncrease() {
        long[] original = {};
        BinaryIndexedTree binaryIndexedTree = new BinaryIndexedTree(original);
        binaryIndexedTree.increase(0, 1);
    }

    @Test(expectedExceptions = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testNoNullArrayAllowed() {
        new BinaryIndexedTree(null);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSumUpTo() {
        BinaryIndexedTree binaryIndexedTree = new BinaryIndexedTree(4);
        binaryIndexedTree.increase(0, 1);
        binaryIndexedTree.increase(1, 2);
        binaryIndexedTree.increase(2, 3);
        binaryIndexedTree.increase(3, 4);
        Assert.assertEquals(binaryIndexedTree.sumUpTo(3), 1 + 2 + 3 + 4);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSize() {
        Assert.assertEquals(new BinaryIndexedTree(0).size(), 0);
        Assert.assertEquals(new BinaryIndexedTree(2).size(), 2);
        Assert.assertEquals(new BinaryIndexedTree(array(1, 2, 3)).size(), 3);
        Assert.assertEquals(new BinaryIndexedTree(array()).size(), 0);
    }

    @Test(expectedExceptions = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testSizeNegativeResultsInProblem() {
        BinaryIndexedTree binaryIndexedTree = new BinaryIndexedTree(-1);
    }

    @Test
    public void testRangeSum() {
        BinaryIndexedTree binaryIndexedTree = new BinaryIndexedTree(4);
        binaryIndexedTree.increase(0, 1);
        binaryIndexedTree.increase(1, 2);
        binaryIndexedTree.increase(2, 3);
        binaryIndexedTree.increase(3, 4);
        Assert.assertEquals(binaryIndexedTree.rangeSum(1, 2), 2 + 3);
        Assert.assertEquals(binaryIndexedTree.rangeSum(0, 0), 1);
        Assert.assertEquals(binaryIndexedTree.rangeSum(1, 1), 2);
        Assert.assertEquals(binaryIndexedTree.rangeSum(2, 2), 3);
        Assert.assertEquals(binaryIndexedTree.rangeSum(3, 3), 4);
        Assert.assertEquals(binaryIndexedTree.rangeSum(1, 3), 2 + 3 + 4);
    }

    @Test
    public void testWithNegativeNumbers() {
        BinaryIndexedTree binaryIndexedTree = new BinaryIndexedTree(array(0, 1, 2, -1, -2, 0, 0));
        Assert.assertEquals(binaryIndexedTree.sumUpTo(binaryIndexedTree.size() - 1), 0);
    }

    private static long[] array(long... elements) {
        return elements;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello,  the constructor `IndexOutOfBoundsException(int index)`  is available only from Java 9.

Comment: I'm using Java 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two suggestions for your code.

1) Make a method to get the last set of bits, instead of repeating the code & comment.

```java
/**
* Faster way to get the last set bit of index using 2's complement
* @param index index in array
*/
private int getLastSetOfBits(int index) {
    return index & (-index);
}
```

2) In the method `BinaryIndexedTree#rangeSum`, since you are using the expression `sumUpTo(toIndex)` in all cases, I suggest that you extract it in a variable.

````java
public long rangeSum(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    long sumUpToFromIndex = sumUpTo(toIndex);

    if (fromIndex == 0) {
        return sumUpToFromIndex;
    }

    return sumUpToFromIndex - sumUpTo(fromIndex - 1);
}
```
````